How to create a "return to steering system" without using LEGO Power Functions for Technic Cars?
I just bought a 42154 Ford GT, and I wanted to make it remote-controlled, but I only have 2 M-motors and an IR receiver. How do I create a return-to-center steering mod for my car?

You can use any rubber band to create a return-to-center mechanism,
but the details are dependent on the size of your model, the available space inside for this mechanism and the force required to overcome the friction of the steering gear train.
If you can share more about your project, we might be able to help you figure out the details - otherwise, you'll probably get a satisfactory result just as quickly by trial and error.

I won't be able to provide a complete solution for your motorization. In the past, when Power Functions system was introduced servo motor wasn't available at first and later was rather expensive. I've seen people using Technic, Axle Connector Rectangular Triple Spring-Loaded in their MOC's to make sure steering returned to center.

There are a few models on Rebrickable that incorporate this part (in different colors, thus multiple pages with MOCs) which you may want to check for inspiration of your own solution.

I was thinking of a solution where I wouldn't have to buy new parts; is there something viable using rubber-bands or something similar?

@Downvolter, What could improved about this answer? Maybe trying to research parts like rubber bands to create an servo?
